# How to do redirecting when a particular url is entered?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a url on my joomla site

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=3220

My Customer wants it to be accessed as

http://www.mysite.com/sales

I have used mod_rewrite to do this it works fine. But i want that when user enters

http://www.mysite.com/sales

it should reach to

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=3220

instead of just showing the content of that url.

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to the base URL? Joomla's SEF support, once enabled (which automates mod_rewrite in a user-friendly manner), will perform routing. It won't redirect to the non-SEF version because that would defeat the object.

Comment: @pharalia need to just do it for single instance not for every url

Comment: @sushilbharwani I'm not clear on this *SEF isn't enabled* ? but your client wants to use a short SEF style url that redirect to the right non-SEF URL?

Comment: @cppl yes. If you forget the sef context (because client doesnt understands it) and just think about it as a better to read url for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a directory under root called `/sales/`
2. Create a file called `index.php` inside `/sales/`...
3. Put this in it:

   ```
   Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
   Header( "Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=3220" );
   ```

Then:

1. Remove your `mod_rewrite` changes.
2. Seriously try and get your client to update to 1.5.25 as there are lots of security fixes since the 1.5.10 code base.

Comment: is there a difference between mod_rewrite and mod_redirect?

Comment: This really needs a new question but quickly: `mod_rewrite` is a more powerful flexible option whereas [`mod_redirect` doesn't exist][1], `Redirect` is a directive of `mod_alias` which is much simpler but lacks the ability to deal with URL attributes etc - `Redirect` is generally a lighter load on the server.

  [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/

Answer (score 1):

get the current page url, if it is sales, then redirect with location header

```
    function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
```

and

```
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=3220");
```

so:

```
$pageurl = curPageURL();

if ($pageurl == "http://www.mysite.com/sales") {
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=3220");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am not aware of Joomla features**

But for a normal php application i would have 
created .htaccess in the parent folder. And redirected all calls to a single file (Front Controller Design Pattern)

The contents of the .htaccess would be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

All the query string will be available in $_GET['url']